finitely generated solvable group of infinite rank
The celebrated theorem of P . Kropholler says that:

If $G$ is a finitely generated solvable group of infinite rank, then
$G$ admits a subquotient isomorphic to $C_p \wr \mathbb{Z} \cong \bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{p}  \rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}$ for
some prime $p$.

Recall that a solvable group $G$ has finite rank if there is $k \geqslant 1$ such that all finitely generated  subgroups of $G$ are generated by at most $k$ elements.
I was wondering if we can assume the subgroup to have a finite index? More specifically, if $G$ is a finitely generated solvable group of infinite rank, does $G$ have a finite index subgroup that has a quotient of the form  $K \rtimes_\phi \mathbb{Z} \leqslant \bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{p}  \rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}$, where $K$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{p} $? (I think all abelian-by-cyclic groups satisfy this)
Any simple counterexample will be really appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Consider the group $\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{3} \rtimes _\phi (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}  ) = \bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{3} \rtimes _\phi ( \langle t_1 \rangle \oplus \langle t_2  \rangle )$, where $t_1$ shifts the index to the right by one, while $t_2$ is an auotmphism on each $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ that sends $1$ to $2$
